# Layered navigation missing attributes

Tags: layered-navigation, ce-1.9.2.4

Around Christmas we have a problem with orders and in the end it looks that is problem from one of the extension. So while we search a issue and try to solve something else happens. All the attributes that are in layered navigation are gone, except for **Brand** and **Product line**. For all of the rest attributes when I check for the items with **getItemsCount()** I get a **0**. Which is not true. I try to refresh all of the indexes and clear cache, the final result is the same.

When I go deeper and deeper the situation become more and more strange for me.

So i try to edit a product attribute value, when i click "**Save and continue edit**" the new value is saved. Example: I open the "**Product one**" and change "**Attribute 1**"(it is a multi select field) from "**Value 1**", "**Value 3**" to "**Value 2**" when I click "**Save and continue edit**" after page refreshed I see message "**The product has been saved.**" and for "**Attribute 1**" is selected only "**Value 2**". Then I go and refresh the page with layered navigation and I still see only two filters "**Brand**" and "**Product line**".

Then I decide to go to "**Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage attributes**" and select the "**Attribute 1**" attribute. Then I set the "**Use In Layered Navigation**" from "**Filterable (with results)**" to "**Filterable (no results)**" and save it. Now refresh the page with layered navigation and I see the "**Attribute 1**", but all values are inactive. So I return the "**Use In Layered Navigation**" to "**Filterable (with results)**" on "**Attribute 1**" attribute. At this point I go to edit the "**Product one**" product again and when i change the "**Attribute 1**" attribute for that product and "**Save and continue edit**", after page reload I see the old value are still selected. If I use the same example as on top when I save the product and page reload I see the for "**Attribute 1**" is still selected "**Value 1**" and "**Value 3**". Then i decide to refresh the page with layered navigation and I see the "**Attribute 1**" attrubute in layered navigation with "**Value 2**" value active to filter. Then I go again to edit the product and change some other attribute they seems to be saved normally.

I am using **Magento 1.9.2.4**.

This is really strange to me. Do you have any explanation and fix for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that the root of the problem is this issue with the orders that we have before Christmas. While I was searching a solution for this problem I try several things. One of witch was to update to latest version of Magento 1.9.3.7 (at this time) via a cPanel **Softaculous apps installer**. Of course I made a backup with same tool to reverse it the update do not help. And in final it looks that this was the case. Several days ago i notice that the reverse do not was very successful because there was some files, that the update add and the backup do not remove. It looks like that this back up do not delete all file in the folder before to extract the back up.

When I found this out I decode, that the best way it will be to update one more time to 1.9.3.7 and see if the filters in layered navigation will work. And that was the case.